# redirect a page to an url with #

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect an url (let's say https://www.example.com/de/page-a/) to an url having a parameter with a # (https://www.example.com/de/page-b/#filter:fields=6).

I don't find the right rule using RewriteRule or Redirect. It always redirects to https://www.example.com/de/page-b/, ignoring the last part.

Can someone help me on that?

Best regards

Comment: "ignoring the last part." - It shouldn't "ignore" the last part (unless you are trying to redirect _from_ a URL with a `#`) - please show what you have tried.

Comment: Redirect ^de/page\-a/$ https://www.exemple.com/de/page-b/#filter:fields=51? [L,R=301]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Redirect ^de/page\-a/$ exemple.com/de/page-b/#filter:fields=51? [L,R=301]
> ```

You are mixing up the directives. The mod_alias `Redirect` directive takes a simple root-relative URL prefix (starting with a slash) as the source URL argument. So the above will never match and nothing happens. There are no `[L,R=301]` *flags* with the `Redirect` directive, which is used by mod_rewrite `RewriteRule`.

For example:

```
Redirect 301 /de/page-a/ /de/page-b/#filter:fields=51
```

You do not need to specify an absolute URL as the target if you are redirecting to the same scheme + hostname.

When redirecting to a fragment identifier (everything after the `#`) you do need to be careful of redirect loops since the *fragid* is not passed back to the server. In this case you are OK since you are redirecting to a different URL-path, ie. `page-a` to `page-b`. But you could not redirect from `page-a` to `page-a` (same URL-path and query string) and simply change the *fragid* as it will create a redirect loop. For this you would need to use JavaScript.

NB: Test with 302 (temporary) redirect first to avoid caching issues.

---

If you want to implement this using mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule`) - perhaps if you are already using mod_rewrite - then you could do the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^de/page-a/$ /de/page-b/#filter:fields=51 [NE,R=301,L]
```

Note that there is no slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

The `NE` flag is required here in order to prevent the `#` being URL-encoded in the response and treated as part of the URL-path.